# Win32 function to OpenFileDialog?

Tags: winapi, openfiledialog

I searching function something like `OpenFileDialog` on `.NET` but on `win32`, i can't find this function on this name on *msdn* and i remember this function exists.

Can anyone give me name?

Greetings,

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [GetOpenFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/nf-commdlg-getopenfilenamea).

Comment: This has been superceded by the Common Item Dialog API.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776913(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Yeah, but IFileDialog on Vista/Win7.

Comment: I would recommend adding an example on how to use this function.

Comment: Updated link to the `IFileDialog` family: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/common-file-dialog

Answer (score 8):

```
//make sure this is commented out in all code (usually stdafx.h)
// #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 

#include <windows.h>

OPENFILENAME ofn;       // common dialog box structure
TCHAR szFile[260] = { 0 };       // if using TCHAR macros

// Initialize OPENFILENAME
ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd;
ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
ofn.lpstrFilter = _T("All\0*.*\0Text\0*.TXT\0");
ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn) == TRUE)
{
    // use ofn.lpstrFile
}
```

Taken from [Displaying Open File Dialog using WinApi](https://iq.direct/blog/57-displaying-open-file-dialog-using-winapi.html)